# Probability distribution over predicted probabilities in multinomial logistics regression

Tags: regression, logistic, predictive-models, multinomial-distribution, prediction-interval

I am currently wondering (and cannot get my head around this) how to get a probability distribution (or something similar to a prediction interval in OLS) for the predicted probabilities of a multinomial logistics regression. I do not have a specific (data) example currently, but the following is what I have in mind.

http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/election-2016/primary-forecast/texas-republican/

Have a look at the candidate-specific distributions below the (main) line chart. To my understanding this gives a probability distribution over the possible outcomes for each candidate. I assume this is based on some kind of multinomial logistic model. In that case, I know how to derive the point estiamte (black dot, labeled "Average" in the charts). However, I have no idea how the probability distribution is calculated.

FiveThirtyEight provides some details on how this is done, which did not help me any further ("Step 4", rather towards the last third of the page):

http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-we-are-forecasting-the-2016-presidential-primary-election/

Interestingly, on this page they say the red areas are confidence intervals. However, should they not be rather something similar to "prediction intervals" in OLS?

Any hint pointing me in the right direction how to calculate these probability distributions would be greatly appreciated. Any correction of potential misunderstandings is also much welcome.